# What is the error syntax error in the last line

Tags: python-3.x

```
def reaction(x):
    if x<7000:
        print('Ahem, can you rethink this 
             number please?')
    elif x>10000:
        print('Wow sis! You ar a queen!')
    elif 7000>x>10000:
        print('Cool, Thanks sis! {} rupees will 
            certainly help'.format(x))
    return
    
money_sis=int(input('How much money can you give me?')
reaction(money_sis)
```

Comment: Just add a parenthesis at the end of the last but one line

Answer (score 0):

As @Riccardo Bucco commented you need to close parenthesis after input() message. The return statement is not complete. Also your 3rd condition seems to be wrong..try this

```
def reaction(x):
if x<7000:
    print('Ahem, can you rethink this number please?')
elif x>10000:
    print('Wow sis! You ar a queen!')
elif 7000<x<10000:
    print('Cool, Thanks sis! {} rupees will certainly help'.format(x))
return

money_sis=int(input('How much money can you give me?'))
print(reaction(money_sis))
```